# cp:omitting directory 'off_web' when I copy my project

Tags: unix, directory, project, cp

In my computer, I want to backup the project, so I copy:

```
cp off_web off_web_bak_20171008
```

But it give the below error:

> cp:omitting directory 'off_web'

Answer (score 0):

You try the below command:

```
cp -r off_web off_web_bak_20171008
```

This error when you execute cp command means under the off_web directory, there are still have directory under the off_web, use `-r` will recursive copy the project.